# how to predict svar models in r?

Tags: r, predict

When I use the var model in R package`vars`, I can use the function `predict` to predict the model.

For example

```
z = VAR(x, p = 1, type = "const")
pred_y = predict(y, n = 1)
```

but when I use the `SVAR` function, `predict` throws an error

```
z = VAR(x, p = 1, type = "const")
y = SVAR(z,Amat = amat,Bmat = NULL) 
predict(y)
```

> Error in is.constant(y) :
>
> (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

VAR, SVAR and SVEC Models: Implementation
Within R Package vars : Bernhard Pfaff

See Section 3. Classes methods and functions

The methods "predict" for SVAR class doesn't exist.
You can use instead the function "fevd" which show us how a shock impact the other variable